# Find identical photos while the file hash is different?

Tags: image, photo

I have two folders with 100% identical photos (and other files that I need). Approximately 100GB + 100GB.

Every pixel is the same, but the hashes does not mach because of the added exif data. I do not want to delete the exif.

Are there any software that can recognise the pixel-same photos and delete one of them, so that only the difference between the folders remains in one of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use ImageMagick's ability to calculate a hash for each file's data - ignoring the EXIF data, like this:

```
identify -format "%# %f\n" *jpg *.png

13604ac55b0af81970c9aa2a7df699f0c34b7bc7676b3cc78cf5f339246a146b tiles.jpg
ccc559642d15d9f6d16d99e5be2a7dae5d13e27cf0f6af974d7c73dd86974e1e 5.png
a136e20c10f161169f3603ad95c4ba31ded66d7e5e9f42233afe5821222b0dd0 7.png
cd46ad516c6fad8f14a80a0c9952a3121b4b123cec84423509ad32fa9ac6bacf a.png
```

Then put that data in a file and run it through `sort` and `uniq` to find duplicates. This has the benefit of not comparing all possible combinations of individual files, but just generating the checksum once for each.

`ImageMagick` is installed on most Linux distors and available for OS X (ideally through `homebrew`, in my opinion) and also Windows - see [here](http://www.imagemagick.org).

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to run this recursively, like `find . -name "*.jpg" -exec identify -format "%# %f\n" {}`, but it gives the error: `find: missing argument to -exec`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can just use `find . -name \*.jpg -exec identify -format "%# %f\n" {} \;`